# DelphiPrism App.g.pas file info

Tags: delphi-prism

What is the  App.g.pas file for?

I'm making an application in Delphi Prism but when I build it I get compiler errors in the  App.g.pas file. When I change them and build my project again, they reappear, because obviously the  App.g.pas file is automatically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the autogenerated part of a WPF application. It's generated from the XAML files